# How to deserialisze an Array of Array of Objects into List of Pojos using Gson

Tags: json, kotlin, gson, deserialization, typetoken

For example:
the POJO is

```kotlin
class Student(val name : String, val age : Int)
```

and the JSON string is

```
[["Avinash", 21], ["Sai", 23], ["pavan", 30]]
```

I want the gson to deserialize the JSON as `List<Student>`, I tried to use the TypeToken but it's not working

Comment: `TypeToken` has nothing to do with it. Why do you think Gson should map `name` and `age` to `[0]` and `[1]` automatically without giving it any hints on how it should do so?

Comment: hmm yes,  is there a way to do that?

Comment: Implement a custom type adapter that would convert array elements to proper `Student` constructor arguments and invoke the constructor.

Comment: Can the `json` be modified? If it can be, I'd start with that, as the currently it's very badly designed where position of element maps to a specific field

Answer (score 1):

thankyou fluffy , this worked for me

data class Student(
val name: String,
val age: Int
)

fun main() {

```
val json = "[['AVINASH' , 21] , ['Sai' , 23]]"
val type = object : TypeToken<List<Student>>() {}.type

val gsonBuilder = GsonBuilder()

gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(Student::class.java, object : JsonDeserializer<Student> {
    override fun deserialize(json: JsonElement, p1: Type?, p2: JsonDeserializationContext?): Student {
        val studentArray = json.asJsonArray
        return Student(studentArray[0].asString , studentArray[1].asInt)
    }

})


var list: List<Student> = gsonBuilder.create().fromJson(json, type)

print(list)
```

}

Comment: Glad you've figured it out. :) However, if it is possible, please follow kdev's advice of fixing the JSON format rather than having it like that.